# JSP variable initialization is happening after JS runs

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay

I'm initializing a JSP string inside a Liferay portlet:

```
String json = "{}";

// returns json
json = LiferayPortlet.makeCurlCall();

...

<script>

$(window).load(function(){

    //initialize js variable
    jsData = "${json}"; 

    // initialize the page
    initializePage(jsData);
});


</script>
```

The issue I'm having is that `LiferayPortlet.makeCurlCall();` is returning json, but `jsData` is not being initialized to it, instead its being set to `""`. Is there a way to initialize `jsData` to the json that is being returned from the function above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't do it

You cannot initialize a JavaScript variable with a scriptlet or JSTL.  The Java code is executed on the server and will not execute in top down order on your jsp page.

While I don't recommend this you can use the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var message = '<c:out value="${json}"/>';
</script>
```

That will technically work - however I want to stress that I do not recommend this.  Maybe you can explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish and we can recommend a more optimal way of doing it.

## JSTL v. Scriplets

You might also have a scope issue using JSTL and scriplets together indiscriminately.  They are of different scopes.  JSTL works with the following scopes.

- page
- request
- session
- application

Scriplets are in the page scope always.  So **while your code doesn't contain this issue** it most likely will be something you will encounter.

### Recommendation

If you are using Liferay, I suggest you learn Alloy UI (a JavaScript library) and become comfortable with their AJAX modules.  Generally, when I see the code you posted, it is better to have an AJAX function that makes a GET call to your portlet for the JSON when it is needed.

Comment: Why the indirection through `jsonToJS`?

Comment: I was rather thinking of omitting the  line, leaving `var message = '<c:out value="${json}"/>';`